# Git log follow renames "forward" like `git blame --reverse`

Tags: git, rename

I would like to know if there's an equivalent of this blame command for `git log`.

```
git blame --incremental --reverse ef907412 -- path/OldName.kt
```

> Notes
>
> - I'm using `--incremental` here because I'd like to process the output, i.e. finding the new names of a file, or if it has been removed. Here I'm trusting Git, whether it is right or not.
> - I'm assuming the `HEAD` as the were I need to find the new name, not every branch.

Which shows me renames that happened after `ef907412`. This works with the [`--reverse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt---reverseltrevgtltrevgt) option

> `--reverse <rev>..<rev>`
>
> Walk history forward instead of backward. Instead of showing the revision in which a line appeared, this shows the last revision in which a line has existed. This requires a range of revision like START..END where the path to blame exists in START. `git blame --reverse START` is taken as `git blame --reverse START..HEAD` for convenience.

Example output

```
ef907412f3fd97366b35dc91f4f34bbda2ef877c 38 38 1
author bric3
author-mail <bric3@example.com>
author-time 1686914826
author-tz +0200
committer bric3
committer-mail <bric3@example.com>
committer-time 1686918382
committer-tz +0200
summary Renames OldName to NewName
boundary
previous 568868295e8de44c117f0b2c57394430cf21e5f0 path/NewName.kt
filename path/OldName.kt
ef907412f3fd97366b35dc91f4f34bbda2ef877c 40 40 1
previous 568868295e8de44c117f0b2c57394430cf21e5f0 path/NewName.kt
filename path/OldName.kt
ef907412f3fd97366b35dc91f4f34bbda2ef877c 50 50 1
previous 568868295e8de44c117f0b2c57394430cf21e5f0 path/NewName.kt
filename path/OldName.kt
ef907412f3fd97366b35dc91f4f34bbda2ef877c 63 63 1
previous 568868295e8de44c117f0b2c57394430cf21e5f0 path/NewName.kt
filename path/OldName.kt
...
additional commits
```

The information is *reversed* so the renamed file is indicated in the `previous` tag word. And the file was renamed in `568868295e8de44c117f0b2c57394430cf21e5f0`.

I tried to do the same with `git log`. `git log` has the `--follow` flag however this seems only working by walking history backward that is from `path/NewName.kt`. While I would like to "follow renames forward".

This next command is the best nearest thing to what I want. It will give what has been either deleted or renamed, between the two commits.

```bash
$ git log --oneline --name-status --diff-filter=RD --find-renames --reverse ef907412..HEAD
56886829 Renames OldName to NewName
R092    path/OldName.kt path/NewName.kt
R091    path/OldName-A.kt path/NewName-A.kt
adddd58a fix: Use custom JBPopup to avoid tooltip flickering
R054    path/OldName-B.kt path/NewName-B.kt
7024dd3d Fix file name typo
R100    path/OldName-C.kt path/NewName-C.kt
8b57692a Rename package
R097    path/OldName-D.kt newpath/NewName-D.kt
R098    path/OldName-E.kt newpath/NewName-E.kt
R097    path/OldName-F.kt newpath/NewName-F.kt
R097    path/OldName-G.kt newpath/NewName-G.kt
R098    path/OldName-H.kt newpath/NewName-H.kt
...
```

This outpout gives me too much information while I'm only looking at a single file (maybe several) that were present in commit `ef907412`.

And as soon as I specify the *pathspec* of the old file name, git bails out on rename detection, probably because the new name does not match the *pathspec*.

```bash
$ git log --oneline --name-status --diff-filter=RD --find-renames --reverse ef907412..HEAD
56886829 Renames OldName to NewName
D       path/OldName.kt
```

Is it feasible with `git log` ? Maybe under the hood operations. Maybe `git blame` is the best option at this time.